# Disabling local resources just for some users accessing a remote desktop session host

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

We are using a VPS running Windows server 2008

We need to disable the access to local resources (printer, local drives, etc) just for some users remotely accessing this VPS, while allowing the use of local resources to other users.

Any idea on how to do this?

I have found a way of disabling the access to local resources for all users, modifying the redirection settings on the RD session host configuration and also through the group policy settings (users and computer configuration), but not just doing that for some users.

Thanks in advance for your help, Fausto

Answer (score 0):

You can add users to a group in AD (run dsa.msi from execute prompt) in windows server 2008 let's say localusers and a remoteusersgroup.
Next you can set the rights to folders to a certain group in the security tab (after rightclicking a folder and selecting propreties). You can give read/write access to the localusers group and deny any access to the remoteusergroup.

The same with printers etc.

Comment: I am afraid I didn't explain myself clearly. When I said Local resources, I meant printer and local drives in the local computer of the user remotely accessing the VPS. Is it better now?